# Why does javascript .replace not work on this array key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here I am adding the text of each '. cmsCategories' div to item_array, but then .replace() won't work on the item_array keys. How can I fix this? (after this I'll write the new contents back into the div). Any help would be awesome!

http://jsfiddle.net/QKHJJ/1/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var item_array=new Array();

$("[class=' cmsCategories']").each(function(i, obj) {
item_array.push(obj.innerHTML);
});

item_array[0].replace("icon_dog", "<img src='img/icon_dog.png' alt='icon_dog' />"); 
item_array[0].replace("icon_cat", "<img src='img/icon_cat.png' alt='icon_cat' />"); 

alert(item_array[0]);


});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="cmsSmartListResults">
  <li>
    <div class=" cmsCategories">icon_cat, apple, icon_dog, pear, banana</div>
    <a href="" class=" cmsPageLink"></a>
    <div class=" cmsDescription"></div>
    <div class=" cmsFileSize"></div>
    <a class=" cmsMoreLink"></a>
</li>
  <li>
<div class=" cmsCategories">apple, icon_dog</div>
<a href="" class=" cmsPageLink"></a>
<div class=" cmsDescription"></div>
<div class=" cmsFileSize"></div>
<a class=" cmsMoreLink"></a>
</li>
  <li>
    <div class=" cmsCategories">pear, banana</div>
    <a href="" class=" cmsPageLink"></a>
    <div class=" cmsDescription"></div>
    <div class=" cmsFileSize"></div>
    <a class=" cmsMoreLink"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** The replace function doesn't change the string you pass (strings are immutable) : it returns a new one.

Do :

```
var newString = item_array[0].replace(...
```

or

```
item_array[0] = item_array[0].replace(...
```

**2)** After this operation, you must change the DOM again with `$('someselector').html(item_array[0]);`

---

The complete code you need is something like

```
$("[class=' cmsCategories']").each(function(i, obj) {
    var html = $(this).html();
    html = html.replace ...
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Comment: Or assign the `replace()`d value back to the original variable.

Comment: Hi I was going to write back to the dom after - if you check the jsfiddle the key value isnt changed by .replace - am i missing something?

Comment: Wow I have definitely learned from using .each and $(this) here- seems quite powerful! thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The replace method does not modify the original value.  You'd have to do something like:

```
item_array[0] = item_array[0]
     .replace("icon_dog", "<img src='img/icon_dog.png' alt='icon_dog' />");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
item_array[0] = 
    item_array[0].replace("icon_dog", "<img src='img/icon_dog.png' alt='icon_dog' />")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your replace statement is incorrect. Try this.

```
item_array[0] = item_array[0].replace("icon_dog", "<img src='img/icon_dog.png' alt='icon_dog' />"); 
item_array[0] = item_array[0].replace("icon_cat", "<img src='img/icon_cat.png' alt='icon_cat' />");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QKHJJ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Updated your jsFiddle, you forgot the array = array.replace.

http://jsfiddle.net/QKHJJ/3/