# How can I conditionally modify the contents of a global object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, replace, global-variables

I have a global var named `inputType` which is a lengthy object:

```
inputType = {
part1: 'string',
part2: 'string2',
...
part100:'last string'
}
```

In a separate piece of code, I have some input fields that receive numeric values. I would like to alter certain parts of the `var` object string as such:

```
<input id='input1'>First input
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#input1').blur(function (){
 var inp = parseInt($('#input1').val(), 10);

 if (inp <10) {
 inputType.part2.replace(/string2/,'some other string'); 
}

});
});

// Then I call this modified  inputType.part2 object in another function
```

// I can't seem to effect the string change when the condition is met? When I try to call this particular object property in another script, the string change is not performed. I also can't see this change on the DOM inspector when I try this out. But this syntax will perform the `replace` function when I try it on the console.

How can I replace or modify `inputType.part2` when the condition is met, and then use the modified object in another piece of code?

Objects are tough!

Thanks.

Comment: [Please read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). `.replace` **returns** a new string. (also `var` is an invalid variable name, but I assume you have a proper name in your code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace method doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work)

Comment: -1 for posting such messy code. indent it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` your object first. Then try to access it with that name.

```
var xObj = {
part1: 'string',
part2: 'string2',
...
part100:'last string'
}

.....

if (inp <10) {
  xObj.part2.replace(/string2/,'some other string'); 
}
```

---

**Edit:**

`.replace()` will not modify the source string. we have to assign the result of `.replace()` back to the source to accomplish the modification.

### [Conceptual DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9czTL/)

Your code should be like this,

```
if (inp <10) {
 xObj.part2 = xObj.part2.replace(/string2/,'some other string'); 
}
```

Please read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to know more about `.replace()`

Comment: I assume that the variable has a proper name in the actual code, otherwise the OP would get a syntax error and the code wouldn't work at all. You haven't fixed the real problem.

Comment: @FelixKling I was confused about it in the beginning, But see OP just mentioned in all places like `var.part2`. Ok let us clarify this with him. :)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. My variable is global with a unique name, I have corrected this in the question. I don't think this is the issue, since I can still reference this particular object property in its unmodified state (even if the condition is met).

Comment: @user1837608 You have to assign it back to the object property to get your concept working.

Comment: Thanks @RajaprabhuAravindasamy for the tip. the missing element was indeed the lack of reassigning the new string back to the object. This is a great help to me! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.InputVal = {
   part1: 'string',
   part2: 'string2',
   ...
   part100:'last string'
}

.....

if (inp <10) {
  window.InputVal.part2 = window.InputVal.part2.replace(/string2/,'some other string'); 
}
```

just 'update' the `window.InputVal.part2` with the new value. Put only the `.replace` will not override the old value.

For example:

```
// define "x"
window.InputVal.x = 1;

// replace value
window.InputVal.x.toString().replace(/1/,'2');

// show
console.log(window.InputVal.x)
// will print 1

// but..if you do:

window.InputVal.x = window.InputVal.x.toString().replace(/1/,'2');
// will print '2'
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please explain the problem and your solution.