# javascript replace all string and variable with global

Tags: javascript, replace

How to replace all sting+variable? Why i can not replace all `[0]` and `[1]` into `new`? Here is some simple example, in the real situation, [0][1][2]... with more condition. Thanks.

```
var a='some thing [0]  [1]  [0]  [1] ';
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  a.replace(new RegExp(" ["+i+"] ", 'g'),' new');
}
alert(a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P8HSA/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

**#1**

Your regular expression is now ( example with 0  `[0]`); This will match `<space>0<space/>` You're probably looking for `" \\["+i+"\\] "` as brackets are a special character,

**#2**

You're not storing the result of the replace, you should do:

`a = a.replace(new RegExp(" \\["+i+"\\] ", 'g'),'new');`

Comebine that, and you get

```
var a='some thing [0]  [1]  [0]  [1] ';
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  a = a.replace(new RegExp(" \\["+i+"\\] ", 'g'),'new');
}
alert(a);
```

[Which outputs (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/huBC9/) `some thingnewnewnewnewnew` and I hope that is the expected result.

Last but not least this is an abuse of regular expressions, and you can easily [have a one line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21561936/1066946).

Answer (score 1):

Replace all numbers between [ and ] to *new*.

```
var a = 'some thing [0]  [1]  [0]  [1] ';

a = a.replace(/\[\d\]/g, 'new');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P8HSA/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var a='some thing [0]  [1]  [0]  [1] ';
a = a.replace(/\[[0-2]\]/g,' new');
alert(a);
```

A for loop is overkill here, since regular expressions can do it out of the box. Also I recommend the literal syntax `/.../`.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P8HSA/6/

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable and `replace` does return the new, modified value. You will have to reassign it to your `a` variable yourself (See [Replace method doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work)):

```
a = a.replace(new RegExp(" ["+i+"] ", 'g'), ' new');
```

Still, that's not enough to make it work since `[]` denote a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in a regex. To match them literally, you will have to escape them with a backslash (and that again in the string literal):

```
a = a.replace(new RegExp(" \\["+i+"\\] ", 'g'), ' new');
```

Now, you could use an actual character class to match all digits from 0 to 2 at once:

```
var a = 'some thing [0]  [1]  [0]  [1] ';
alert(a.replace(/\[[0-3]\]/g, ' new')); // regex literal to simplify syntax
```