# Formatting a number to include a thousands-separting comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I am working on a project at work where I want to format values on a table from (128879) to look like this (128,879). The code I have used so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tableOne tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
    var num = $(this).text;
    num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}); });
```

Also, I tried the jQuery `NumberFormatter` Library, but an error code shows that jQuery is not defined (the last line of code on the debugger page using Chrome) and Math.js (no luck). Not sure why this is happening.

The `<script>` tag used for the jQuery and Math.js is shown below:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' src ="jquery.numberformatter-1.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="math.js"></script>
```

Comment: `num.toString().replace(`…`);` by itself doesn’t actually update anything. It should probably be `$(this).text = num.toString().replace(`…`);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace method doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) library so you can use `$` like you want. Also, `$(this).text` is a function; you want `num = $(this).text()` and `$(this).text(num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"))`. I have not tested your regex, so I don't know if it would work.