# Javascript to replace placeholder variable values

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I am trying to replace a string which has place holders with values in an object

For Example:

```
let contentString = `
    I, <<firstName>> <<lastName>>, born on <<DOB>> of <<flatNumber>> , <<houseNumber>>
`;


let data = {
  firstName: 'test_firstName',
  lastName: 'test_lastName',
  DOB: '10-12-1987',
  flatNumber: '3',
  houseNumber: '8'
};

function createTemplate(contentString, data) {
  let pattern = /<<(\w*?)>>/gm;


  while (matches = pattern.exec(contentString)) {

    contentString.replace(matches[1], function replacer(match) {
      console.log(match);
      //contentString = contentString.replace(match, data[match]);
    });

  }

  console.log(contentString);


}

createTemplate(contentString, data);
```

The console.log function in the replacer callback function extracts all the values such as firstName,lastName,DOB,flatNumber and houseNumber.

However, once i uncomment the next line of code which is string replace although the firstName is replaced by the value the `<<lastName>>` is never replaced.

Whereas if i change the contentString to something like

```
let contentString = `
    I, <<firstName>> asnasas  <<lastName>>, born on <<DOB>> of <<flatNumber>> , <<houseNumber>>
`;
```

inserting some text between the `<<firstName>>` and `<<lastName>>` it works.

Can anyone please guide is towards my mistake. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using `replace` with a replacer callback function anyway, why don't you simply use `return contentString.replace(pattern, …)` instead of using the loop and `exec()`?

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like a duplicate of [Replace method doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1433212/1048572)?

Comment: Why not just use a regular expression and replace `"<<"+key+">>"` with `value` for your `data` object?

Comment: Your `while` loop does not work because you are changing `contentString` within the loop body, without adjusting `pattern.lastIndex`.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for the comments. But can you kindly please guide me with an example of using pattern.lastIndex

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - Thank you for your comments. Not sure if i am moving in the right direction but if i have to implement your suggestion then let matches = contentString.replace(pattern,? ); what should i replace the ? with so that the key value suggestion would work

Comment: @Anand [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cronueqz/) of what I mentioned. So you go though `data` with something like `for(key in data)` then do `contentString = contentString.replace("<<"+key+">>","g"), data[key])`. In the example I used a regexp so it replaces all values if there are many.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - Thank you very much for your time and update. really appreciate your help