# Transform part of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, regex, string, replace

I am trying to parse a media query with Javascript.

I intend the mark-up string to look like this

```
@media not screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url(email-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {  
   color: red; 
}
```

Will an output:

```
@media not screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .foo{
        padding-left: 30px;
        background: url(email-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
   .foo{ 
      color: red; 
   }
}
```

So far I have this

```
const css =  `@media (max-width: 600px) {   color: red;    }`
const pattern = new RegExp('@media[^{]+([\s\S]+})\s*')

const cssnew = css.replace( pattern, (full,match) => `{ .foo${match}}` );
//   cssnew === "@media (max-width: 600px) {  .foo{ color: red;  }  }"
```

This Regex look like it working for 1(`@media`)  https://regex101.com/r/r0sWeu/1
and thats ok... but the **replace** function is not getting called?

Thanks for an help

Comment: it doesn't work for `cssnew` value https://regex101.com/r/iT2eR5/17

Comment: Sorry the link was using an old regx 

It works using `@media[^{]+([\s\S]+})\s*`    

TRY: https://regex101.com/r/r0sWeu/1

Comment: `cssnew = cssnew.replace(/@media[^{]+([\s\S]+})\s*/g, '{ .foo $1}')`. You made several very common mistakes here.

Comment: Strings are immutable, meaning you can't modify an existing string, you can only create a new string with the modifications. The `replace()` function returns this new modified string but you're not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the code as follows:

```js
const cssnew =  ` @media (max-width: 600px) {   color: red;    }`
const pattern = /(@media[^{]+{\s*)([\s\S]+?)(\s*})/g

console.log(cssnew.replace( pattern, "$1.foo{\n\t\t$2\n\t}$3" ));
```

Notes:

- Inside regex constructors, backslash is used to form escape sequences, and to define a literal backslash, [it must be doubled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066). It is easier to go with a regex literal, `/pattern/`, where you do not need to double the backslashes
- The new value should be assigned to a variable you want to modify as [strings are immutable in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work)
- There is no need to use a callback inside a replace method if you just want to use a capturing group value, just use backreference `$1` that will get the value stored in Group 1.
- Also, the `[\s\S]+` is too greedy, to get up to the first `}`, use a lazy version, `[\s\S]+?`.

Comment: Thanks, but It don't match the example output in the question. How would I get `@media (max-width: 600px) { .foo { color: red; }  }`?

Comment: You cannot match nested chars with JS regex. You need to build a parsing code. Do you need to match everything from `@media` and the next `{` up to the  next matching `}`?

Comment: Do you need to match everything from @media and the next { up to the next matching }? Yes!

Comment: @codemeasandwich: Could you please still confirm which text you try to match: 1) https://regex101.com/r/oq9QJp/1 and 2) https://regex101.com/r/oq9QJp/2 (these are not solutions, just need clarification what text you need to analyze).

Comment: 1 - I want to inject/wrap with a class(or css select)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149919/discussion-between-codemeasandwich-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: @codemeasandwich Try `cssnew.replace( pattern, "$1.foo{\n\t\t$2\n\t}$3" );` with `/(@media[^{]+{\s*)([\s\S]+?)(\s*})/g` pattern.

Comment: Yes. that work https://jsfiddle.net/codemeasandwich/w6gg8ycm/ Please update you answer's code example with this and I can mark it as correct :)
Big thanks for you help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are escape characters in strings as well. Change `'@media[^{]+([\s\S]+})\s*'` to `'@media[^{]+([\\s\\S]+})\\s*'`

Comment: Thanks, but It don't match the example output in the question. How would I get `@media (max-width: 600px) { .foo { color: red; }  }`?