# How to replace white space with the equivalent special character in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say we have:

```
Saudi Arabia
```

If I do:

```
loc.replace(/ /g,''));
```

Becomes:

```
SaudiArabia
```

What if I want to replace the white space with `&nbsp`?

Tried:

```
loc.replace(/ /g,'&nbsp')
```

I am looking for

```
Saudi&nbspArabia
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's not tho, if I then output loc i get `data-value="SaudiArabia"`

Comment: That works just fine: http://jsbin.com/vogixewogo/edit?html,js,output. (Side note: It's `&nbsp;`, not just `&nbsp`.) See also [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work), if you're really doing what you've shown (but then your first one wouldn't work either). If that's not the problem, please update the question with details.

Comment: [mcve] please – either you forgot to remove the first regex, or the string doesn't contain what you think it contains, or something sanitizes the string before placing it into the attribute, or any other reason that can't really be guessed without seeing the code.

Comment: @JJJ the answer actually does what I am asking..

Comment: @rob.m - Ah, good! :-)

Comment: That means that the space between the words isn't a "normal" space, otherwise `/ /g` would have worked as well.

Comment: @JJJ yes it's what I am thinking, because while the answer shows the correct result on here, on my real case I am stille seeing SaudiArabia with no space, and I need to create the space with html special character not just " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this

```js
var loc = "soudi arabia";
loc = loc.replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;');
console.log(loc)
```

Comment: yes exactly, thanks