# Remove all symbols, html and special chars from string

Tags: javascript

How can I remove all elements from a string apart from raw text and a single space? However, certain symbols are not getting removed, `- , &#8211;, &#8217;`

Currently I use:

```
let descriptionString = description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "").replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,"");
```

`description` is a field from `wordpress` which can contain anything, html, symbols, encoded chars etc.

Example content is:

`Surgical Sim 8211 Kate O8217Connor  Sim Lab` I need to remove `8217` - its only removed the hash at the moment.

I need to display the result in a `react-native View`. I don't want to use a `WebView`to render `html`.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. What is `description`? 2. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work), you're not using the result of the second `replace`.

Comment: Still doesn't remove everything I need to get removed.

Comment: Assuming you're running this in a browser, have you considered inserting this as the innerHTML of a div element (not in the DOM) and retrieving the *textContent*?

Comment: Its for a `react-native` view

Comment: Again: What's in `description`? Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below function. It removes all the special charactors, html and symbols.

```
function filterString(html)
    {
       var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
       tmp.innerHTML = html;
       tmp = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";

       tmp =tmp.replace(/([,"'0-9\-.~!@#$%^&*()_+=–’`{}\[\]\|\\:;"<>\/?])+/g, '').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g,'');
       return tmp;
    }

    console.log(filterString("<html>asdasjhd<body>%dasd test - , ' &#8211;, &#8217; ytest jsdnja  @!@#@&^$@$ &nbsp;"));
```

Also you can test it for your string

```
console.log(filterString("Surgical Sim 8211 Kate O8217Connor  Sim Lab"));
```

Comment: I get `document is not defined` I'm running the code in `react-native`

Comment: I didn't have any idea about react-native. Check why document object is not defined. It worked for me in JS