# How would you refactor this Javascript object looping?

Tags: javascript, object, optimization

I wrote out this basic functionality in ES5 that works for browsers. What it's supposed to do is iterate over a list of character/ encoding pairings and convert them through a passed string/ query. I know there is probably a sleeker way of writing this archaic code style. Would you guys mind taking a minute to share your implementation?

I have been writing Python for a year now and am rusty in ES7.

```
function encodeURLBreakers(query) {
    var URLBreakers = {
        '/': '%2F',
        '?': '%3F',
        '#': '%23'
    }; 
    for (var key in URLBreakers) {
        var reg = '/' + URLBreakers[key] + '/g';
        query.replace(key, reg);
    }   
    return query;
}
```

What would be a good way to refactor this into a reusable function using a map type loop over the Javascript Object.

This is all I've tried and it works, but it uses old syntax. I am very interested in learning and using modern JS (ES7) paradigms to improve my code.

Comment: Did you mean `var reg = new RegExp(URLBreakers[key], 'g')`? Also [your `replace` call doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433212/1048572).

Comment: Btw, why not just use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: Or, if you happen to be constructing a querystring, [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), I'd probably use the callback functionality of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
function encodeURLBreakers(query) {
    const URLBreakers = {
        '/': '%2F',
        '\\?': '%3F',
        '#': '%23'
    };
    const regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(URLBreakers).join("|"), "g");
    return query.replace(regex, match => URLBreakers[match]);
}
```

Made into a reusable function:

```
function makeReplacer(map) {
    const regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join("|"), "g");
    return string => string.replace(regex, match => map[match]);
}

const encodeURLBreakers = makeReplacer({
    '/': '%2F',
    '\\?': '%3F',
    '#': '%23'
});
```

This uses regex alternatives as a trick to avoid looping altogether. If you absolutely had to do it iteratively (e.g. because order mattered, and some expressions matched results of earlier replacements), I'd go for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
function encodeURLBreakers(string) {
    return [
         [/\//g, '%2F'],
         [/?/g, '%3F'],
         [/#/g, '%23'],
    ].reduce(
         (str, [regex, replacement]) => str.replace(regex, replacement),
         string
    );
}
```

Comment: You might need `.join("|\\")` to deal with RegExp special characters.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, I didn't escape the regexes since I didn't expect special characters, but no just prefixing some of them with ``\`` [doesn't suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1048572)

Comment: I know that it's not entirely generic, but I believe it would solve the problem as presented.  I believe your first two examples will fail on `new RegExp('/|?|#', 'g')` as that isn't an allowable regex string.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Oops, I totally missed the `?` which of course is a special character...

Answer (score 0):

Very much related to Bergi's answer, with just a slightly different flavor, is this:

```js
const URLBreakers = {
    '/': '%2F',
    '?': '%3F',
    '#': '%23'
}

const changes = Object .entries (URLBreakers) .map 
  ( ([unsafe, safe]) => [new RegExp (`\\${unsafe}`, 'g'), safe]
  )

const encodeURLBreakers = (str) => 
  changes .reduce
    ( (s, [regex, safe]) => s .replace (regex, safe)
    , str
    )

console .log (
  encodeURLBreakers ('aaa/bbb?#ccc') //~> 'aaa%2Fbbb%3F%23ccc'
)
```

If you don't want to use this as a module and want to encapsulate the helpers, just wrap everything in an IIFE, returning the final function and assign the results to `encodeURLBreakers`.

Note that we escape the characters as we create regexes out of them.  `'?'` for instance, is not the valid body of a regex.  This is not as generic as we might like.  See the comments to Bergi's answer for a more complete answer to that.

Finally, note that one of the characters you would really need to escape in true query strings is `%`.  If you actually need to do that, this won't suffice, since you'd hit an infinite regress as your result added more `%`s; you'd have to use something more like Bergi's first version, perhaps with the regex escaping I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re converting single characters, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is a way to make an array from a transformation of each codepoint of a string (or each element of any iterable in general):

```js
const substitute = map => c => {
    const t = map.get(c);
    return t === undefined ? c : t;
};

const translateString = map => text =>
    Array.from(text, substitute(map)).join('');

const encodeURLBreakers = translateString(new Map([
    ['/', '%2F'],
    ['?', '%3F'],
    ['#', '%23'],
]));


console.log(encodeURLBreakers('hello? world?'));
```

Almost everything here is ES6, so that’s as ES6y as I can make it. :)