# Replace part of string using forEach?

Tags: javascript

I have input boxes ID labeled with the prefix "add-product-" and I want to replace the "add-product-" with nothing. So I tried using `data[field.id].replace("add-product-", "");` but it gives me the error: `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[field.id].replace')`

Here is my code:

```
function addproduct(){

    var datafeilds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='add-product-']"));
    var data = {};
    datafeilds.forEach(function(field){
        data[field.id].replace("add-product-", "");
        data[field.id] = field.value;
    });

    console.log(data);
}
```

The output is:

```
[Log] {add-product-name: "", add-product-overlay1: "", add-product-overlay2: "", add-product-wholesale_price: "", add-product-delivery_price: "", …}
```

I want it to be:

```
[Log] {name: "", overlay1: "", overlay2: "", wholesale_price: "", delivery_price: "", …}
```

Comment: can you please paste the value of  "datafeilds" ?

Comment: You meant `field.id.replace(…)` instead of `data[field.id].replace(…)` I suppose?

Comment: @Bergi I tried both. Not working

Comment: And notice that [`replace` doesn't "change" anything but returns a new string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433212/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` before the you add into the empty obj again. Also you do not need to use `Array.From` in your `datafeilds` as [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns all the `nodes` in an array by default.

Run snippet below to see it working and all replaced.

```js
function addproduct() {

  var datafeilds = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='add-product-']")
  var data = {};
  datafeilds.forEach(function(field) {
    //replace all add-products with ""
    var replace = field.id.replace("add-product-", "");
    //Push to data {}
    data[replace] = field.value

  });
  console.log(data)
}

addproduct()
```

```html
<input id='add-product-name' value="1" />
<input id='add-product-overlay1' value="1" />

<input id='add-product-overlay2' value="1" />
<input id='add-product-wholesale_price' value="1" />
<input id='add-product-delivery_price' value="1" />
```

Comment: The code snippet you posted doesn't work... the 1's are being displayed.

Comment: No... it's not...: {
  "name": "",
  "overlay1": "",
  "overlay2": "",
  "wholesale_price": "",
  "delivery_price": ""
}  they should have "1"'s in there. The values aren't coming though.

Comment: @tony Can you clarify what you want ? This is what you said `I want it to be:` - Exactly thats how it being display in `console.log`

Comment: "name": "" - > "name": "1"

Answer (score -1):

your data object is empty , so accessing field.id property on it will return undefined. So you are getting the above error.

Regarding prefix id you can achieve by making `document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='prefixvalue']")`

Comment: So how can I do it then?